# How to serialize a POJO that only holds a Map attribute?

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am trying to serialize a POJO (class EntriesResponse) with two public classes as key/value pairs of the only attribute (Map) in the class. The POJO, only holds this Hashmap for now so that is the only entity to serialize. The problem is that if the Hashmap is empty I get an output like this:

```
{
    "entries": {}
}
```

But when I put any key/value pair to the map then nothing is returned (literally nothing). Therefore, I am guessing there is a problem serializing the map but no exceptions are caught. So far I can see that both the Key and Value classes (which are not the same) have toString, hashCode, equals, etc. methods and I thought that this was all that Jackson needed to serialize, but I might be wrong. I must mention that these KeyClass and ValueClass (shown in the map below) are public classes but I am not willing to extend them or modify them (if possible) thus I am looking for a solution in which no modification or extension of these classes is needed. I have tried to return Map type of attributes and it worked so as I said I am pretty sure the error comes from using the special key and value classes.

Some examples of the Java classes mentioned above:

EntriesResponse (POJO):

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "entries"
})

public class EntriesResponse implements Serializable {

    @JsonProperty("entries")
    private Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> mapEntries = null;


    public EntriesResponse(){
        this.mapEntries = new HashMap<>();
    }

    public Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> getMapEntries () {
        return this.mapEntries ;
    }

    public void setMapEntries (Map<KeyClass, ValueClass> mapEntries) {
        this.mapEntries = mapEntries;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) {
            return true;
        }
        if (!(o instanceof EntriesResponse )) {
            return false;
        }
        EntriesResponse that = (EntriesResponse ) o;
        return Objects.equals(getMapEntries(), that.getMapEntries());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(getMapEntries());
    }

}
```

How I serialize the POJO:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

String json = "";

try {
    json = mapper.writeValueAsString(entriesResponse);
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

An aprox. example of the the KeyClass (could also apply for ValueClass) of the Map above:

```java
public class KeyClass{

    /*A prioiri, irrelevant code here*/

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return /*Code*/;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) {
        /*Code*/
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        final StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(/*size*/);
        /*More code*/
        return builder.toString();
    }

    /*A priori, irrelevant code here*/
}
```

Comment: Provide the pojo class for more details.

Comment: It is in the first line "POJO (class EntriesResponse)"

Comment: You say "nothing is returned", but your code strongly implies that the `try` completes abruptly. Use a debugger, and start by printing the value of `json` inside your `try` block after assignment.